# MagicMock object evaluates to False

Tags: python, unit-testing, nonetype

I have a Python class like this:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, client=None):
    self._client = client or Client()

  def encode(self, **kwargs):
    encoded = self._client.encode(**kwargs)
    [...]
```

So the pattern here is that `MyClass` can use a `Client` specified during intitialization. If none is specified, the constructor initializes a new `Client` object.

I wanted to test this class, passing a mocked `Client` instance:

```
with patch("Client", autospec=True) as mock_client:
    my_class = MyClass(client=mock_client)
    my_class.encode()
    [...]
```

I noticed that, other than expected, a new `client` object is initialized in `MyClass.__init__()`.
When debugging, it turned out that the reason for that is that the mocked client evaluates to `False`:

```
bool(mock_client)
False
```

I can actually rewrite my constructor like this to make it work as intended:

```
self._client = Client() if client is None else client
```

But that seems more cumbersome. It is also confusing why `bool(mock_client)` evaluates to `False` whereas `mock_client is None` is `True`.

The [documentation about Boolean expressions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) states this:

> the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true

I don't see why a `MagicMock` object should evaluate to `False` according to this definition.

When I create the mock object like this, it does evaluate to `True`:

```
mock_client = patch("Client", autospec=True)

bool(mock_client) # -> True
```

In this case, however, the mocked client seems to lack the specs, so I get this error:

```
E       AttributeError: '_patch' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

The first approach using `patch` as context manager is preferable, and recommended by [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch). It generally seems to be in line with my expectations too, except that it evaluates to `False`.

Is there a way to handle this without changing my code? I find `if client is None Client() else client` much less readable than `client or Client()`.

Furthermore, I don't understand why `bool(mock_client)` evaluates to `False` at all. Is that a bug or a feature in `unittest.mock`?

Comment: You want a mock client but you're using `patch` on `MyClass`.  Don't you want to patch `Client`?

Comment: @Kyle you're right, that was a copy paste error. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking None is better as that is the exact default.   Otherwise you need to make sure the client can never evaluate as false eg if it had a length or its own bool.  However, if that is ok...

The mock you pass has to provide the encode() function like in the documentation link you provided.  But you seem to be mocking the class you are testing.  (Also, as far as I can see the context manager mock_client does evaluate as True.)

In your example what are you trying to test - is it that the client is called?  IE that the `self._client.encode(**kwargs)` was run?   In which case a simple magicmock will do:

```
mock_client = unittest.mock.Mock()
myclass = MyClass(client=mock_client)
myclass.encode(xxx=1, yyy=2)
mock_client.encode.assert_called_once()
mock_client.encode.assert_called_with(xxx=1, yyy=2)
```

Comment: That does look better indeed, but only when using `mock_client = MagicMock()`. With `Mock()`, my code runs into a RuntimeError when the `encode()` results are further processed.

Comment: In your snippet you dont use any returned value from the encode() call.   You can make the mock provide return data or create a side effect if you need to.

Comment: True, I should have included more of the actual encode function. It continues with processing the client response. Their content does not matter for the test, but their type does. This works fine with a MagicMock.